# Javascript Graphing Utility - Multiple Y axis for Line Graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to plot more than 2 y-axes with any of the javascript graphing libraries out there?  [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is the best one I've seen, but it only covers 2 y axes.

Comment: also found this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes/grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) is a substantially more powerful visualization tool, and it should be able to handle your use-case.  However, be prepared to write a lot more code than you would have with Flot.

Comment: Holy hell that must be academic.  This is like the MATLAB of javascript graphing.  Good find nonetheless.

Comment: update: looks like this project is replaced by the D3 project - https://github.com/mbostock/d3

Comment: Yup, D3 is the way to go these days.